# Can expectations be substantiated?

Tags: verbs

I just read the below sentence. Is it possible to have expectations substantiated? Would it not be better to use met or realized?

There is risk of disappointment if expectations are not substantiated.

Comment: Whilst the words you suggest would be more usual, I don't see much wrong with *substantiated*. It carries a slightly different nuance to the others, i.e. of the expectations being *substantially*, but perhaps not *fully* met/realised.

Comment: "Fulfilled" instead of "substantiated" ?

Comment: @Monzoor But suppose you want to recognise that whilst the expectations have not been entirely fulfilled, they have substantially been so?

Comment: In that case, as WS2 comment mentions, "expectations substantially met/ realized/ fulfilled" can be a suitable phrase in this context.

Comment: An interpretation of the sentence is: *One may be disappointed by the results if the intended goal lacks justification*.

Answer (score 1):

**To meet or match expectations** can be defined by

> to be as successful as people think someone or something should be

according to [Merrian Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/match/meet%20expectations). It is more common to say **expectations are not met**, and "met" can be replaced with other words such as "matched", "realized", and "fulfilled" (credit given to other users in the comments). Although these words are more common, "substantiated" can still be used here, for **substantiate**, according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/substantiate), means

> to establish by proof or competent evidence

Synonyms for **substantiate** include **verify**, **support**, and **uphold**.

Despite the word's more conventional usage in giving support for claims/statements, you can think of the phrase, **expectations are not substantiated**, as a way of saying that certain goals were not established by substance; hence there is no way to show people that expectations have been met.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is the idea of disappointment. Disappointment occurs when the expectation is not being maintained, not when it has failed to come true.

If you expect to be able to get gas in the next ten miles, that expectation can be substantiated when you top the hill and see a gas station. If you don't see a gas station when you top the hill, and your expectation is not substantiated, you may be disappointed, even though you later find one. So there is a difference between *substantiated* and *fulfilled*. Substantiation is what you need to preserve the expectation and avoid disappointment.

This from MW's synonym discussion -

> substantiate implies the offering of evidence that sustains the contention

"Substantiate." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 30 Dec. 2016.